# Java buffered reader stops reading lines, if i add a if statement in the while loop:

Tags: java, buffered

I am creating a game engine from scratch with java, i have started work on a new save file instead of using imaages for maps:

Works and prints out every line:

```
while ((readString = buf.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println("Failed to assign action to line: " + readString);
}
```

Doesnt work, prints out first 3 lines:

```
while ((readString = buf.readLine()) != null) {
                if (readString.contains("Width:")){
                    readString.replace("Width:", "");
                    readString.trim();
                    Integer.parseInt(readString);
                    System.out.println(readString);
                }else if (readString.contains("Height:")){
                    readString.replace("Height::", "");
                    readString.trim();
                    Integer.parseInt(readString);
                    System.out.println(readString);
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Failed to assign action to line: " + readString);
                }
}
```

As you can see, the top one is working and prints out every line to the console, the second one stops after reading the 3rd line. I haven't found anything while researching the problem, and my syntax appears to be correct. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to see how to include code in questions. It's really not great for the code to be on a different site.

Comment: My guess is that an exception is being thrown - possibly by Integer.parseInt - but that maybe you're swallowing it.

Comment: Another thing to try would be to copy the String before calling methods on it (and then calling those methods on the copy), though it *should* not make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably an exception that you are swallowing (catching and ignoring) un your program and this is the most probable candidates:

Strings are immutable so when you replace / trim the original string is the same, and a new one is returned.

```
} else if (readString.contains("Height:")){
    readString.replace("Height::", "");
    readString.trim();
    Integer.parseInt(readString);
```

Here you ignore the returned (new) strings and keep operating on the original string. Also, as you can see you check for `Height:` and the you remove `Height::` (notice the double colon). So, unless your data actually contains `Height::` the `Height:` will be left in the string when calling `Integer.parseInt` this causing an exception.

It should be more like this

```
} else if (readString.contains("Height:")){
    readString = readString.replace("Height:", "");
    readString = readString.trim();
    Integer.parseInt(readString);
```

Answer (score 5):

There probably is an exception that you are not seeing.

Put this around your code:

```
try {
   //.. your while-loop here
}
catch(Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then fix the error.

Another hint: `readString.replace("Width:", "")`, `readString.trim()` and `Integer.parseInt(readString)` won't work.
The functions don't change the variable itself, you need to assign their results to a variable.

Example:

```
 readString = readString.trim();
```

Comment: Although it's probably better practice to store the string in another variable rather than change the initial value.

Comment: Ok thank you people, @JamoBox i would but theres no point, when im not doing anything to the line other than reading it in to set variables

Comment: Hence the use of the phrase "better practice"